# Equivalent to EndL for VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I'm building s string and I'd like it to be organized line by line with each entry. So simply put, what is the equivalent of EndL in VBA?

**Here's my code:**

```
If chkMonA = True Then
    additionString = additionString + "Monday"
End If
If chkTuesA = True Then
    additionString = additionString + "Tuesday"
End If
If chkWedA = True Then
    additionString = additionString + "Wednesday"
End If
If chkThursA = True Then
    additionString = additionString + "Thursday"
End If
If chkFriA = True Then
    additionString = additionString + "Friday"
End If
```

For those who dont know any C++ I'll give an example of what im trying to do. Say chkTuesA, chkThursA, and chkFriA all are true. I want the additionStrings output to look like this:

```
Tuesday
Thursday
Friday
```

Comment: VBA has built in constants for both `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` *carriage returns* and the simpler `Chr(10)` line feed. They are simply `vbCrLf` and `vbLf` respectively. BTW, those string concatenations should probably be using the ampersand (&) rather than the plus (+) operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vbLf  (Lf = line feed)

```
additionString = additionString + "Monday" + vbLf
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the output is a string separated by line breaks and is not an array I would I just write a function like this:

```
Function AddToString(byval sAdditionString as string, sDay as string) as String

Dim sReturn as String

sAdditionString = iif(sAdditionString="", _
  sReturn = sDay, sReturn = sAdditionString & vbNewLine & sDay)

AddToString = sReturn

end function
```

and call like this:

```
additionString = AddToString(additionString,"Monday")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `VBNewLine` or `VBLf` to return a new line.